# My topology's processing rate is about 2500 messages per seconds, but Complete latency is about 7ms. Shouldn't it be equal 1000 / 2500 = 0.4ms?

Tags: apache-storm

My topology reads from RabbitMQ, and it's processing rate is about 2500 messages per seconds, but Complete latency is about 7ms. Shouldn't it be equal 1000 / 2500 = 0.4ms?

Topology summary:

[image: Topology summary]

Please, help me to understand, what does mean parameter Complete latency in my case.
Topology process messages from RabbitMQ queue with rate about 2500/sec

RabbitMQ screenshot:

[image: RabbitMQ screenshot]

Comment: Hm why do you think that latency is related to throughput?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Storm docs](https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0/Metrics.html) *The complete latency is just for spouts. It is the average amount of time it took for ack or fail to be called for a tuple after it was emitted.*
So, it is the time between your rabbitmq-spout emitted tuple and the last bolt acked it.

Storm has an internal queue to make pressure, the maximum size of this queue is defined in topology.max.spout.pending variable in configs. If you set it to a high value your rabbit consumer would read messages from the rabbit to fulfil this queue ahead of real processing with bolts in topology, causing the wrong measure of real latency of your topology.

In the RabbitMQ panel, you see how fast messages are consumed from it, not how they are processed, you compare hot and round.

To measure latency I would recommend running your topology for a couple of days, 202 seconds according to your screenshot is too tight.